# Insert data from MSSQL into SQLite in Python3

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlite

I am using Python 3.6. I have a large table in MSSQL in which I want to pull the data out process it in python and then save the data. Currently I am having issues with sqlite and pyodbc returned values:

```
import sqlite3
import pyodbc

tempConn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = tempConn.cursor()
c.execute(
    ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses
    (
         amt NUMERIC,
         city text,
         statecode text,
         zipcode text
    )
    '''
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=<server>;'
    r'DATABASE=<database>;'
    r'UID=user;'
    r'PWD=password'
)

conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 10 fd.Amt, fd.City, fd.StateCode, fd.ZipCode FROM <large table> AS fd")
index = 1
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print('Row Data:')
    print(row)
    print('')
    try:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (?,?,?,?)", row)
        rowcount = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM addresses")
    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('er: ', er.Message)
    print(rowcount)
```

The error I am recieving is:

> Row Data: (Decimal('1000.000'), 'Chicago', 'IL', '9999')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dataaccess.py", line 37, in
>   
>       c.executemany("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (?,?,?,?)", row) ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

I believe it is because the pyodbc returned decimal is inserting a "Decimal('')" although I do not know how to validate that. How do I insert this data from MSSQL into sqlite in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `float()` to convert the `Decimal('##')` which requires expanding *row* items.

```
for row in rows:
    ...
    c.execute("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
              (float(row[0]), row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Also, `executemany` in this context would be same as `execute` since you pass one list and not a list of lists/tuples. To use the bulk operator, bypass the `for` loop (still needing to expand):

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
c.executemany("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
              [(float(row[0]), row[1], row[2], row[3]) for row in rows])
```